# foreach row insert to another table and update column

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Situation: `Table1` with `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY` to `Table2` named `Table2Id`

How to update `Table2Id` column for each row in `Table1` with newly inserted row from `Table2` (each `Table1` row will have its own `Table2` record)?

Comment: A simple update statement should work for Table1 as long as the rowid exists in Table2. Are you having trouble in getting the newly inserted rowID from Table2?

Comment: It should insert data to `Table2` for each row in `Table1` and in same time assign `INSERTED.Id` to appropriate column in `Table1`

Answer (score 0):

I have used code like the following to perform this on MS SQL-Server. I don't have the code handy, but have implemented similar triggers in MySQL.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Addresses_afterInsert] 
   ON  [dbo].[Addresses] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [MultiKey] ([keyEntity], [nameEntity], [typeEntity])
  SELECT [keyAddress], [fullAddress], 'Address' AS [typeEntity]
  FROM [Addresses]
  WHERE ([keyMulti] IS NULL);
  UPDATE [Addresses]
  SET [keyMulti] = [MultiKey].[keyMulti]
  FROM [Addresses]
  INNER JOIN [MultiKey]
    ON (
      ([MultiKey].[keyEntity] = [Addresses].[keyAddress])
      AND ([MultiKey].[typeEntity] = 'Address')
    );
END
```